# How to rotate servers with PHP?

Tags: php

I have identical backend applications running on several servers and a PHP frontend that can request data from them. So when a user comes and wants to request data, PHP has to request it from one backend server which is then doing some calculations and stuff.

Currently I'm selecting the backend server to request data from this way:

```
    $servers = array(
        array('IP', 'PORT'),
        array('IP', 'PORT'),
        array('IP', 'PORT'),
        array('IP', 'PORT'),
        array('IP', 'PORT'),
        array('IP', 'PORT'),
        array('IP', 'PORT'),
        array('IP', 'PORT')
    );
    $server = $servers[mt_rand(0,count($servers)-1)];
```

But now this is not perfectly rotated, it's pretty random and with an unlucky streak this could lead to one server being overloaded and another one being idling, I would prefer to have them properly rotated to always have them roughly at the same workload. This would also make it easier to analyze userflow and see when new backend servers are needed.

What would be the most performant way to rotate the servers without randomizing? Should I make a text file, call it "rotation.txt" and simply put in the $servers index of the last request and next time take `($lastUsedIndex + 1) % count($servers)`? That would include alot of writing files to the disk with a website which often has thousands of concurrent users. Would it be faster to make a MySQL table `rotation` and insert the last used $servers index? Or is there a totally different way that I currently can't think of?

EDIT:

PHP will request the data as json like this: `$fp = @fsockopen($server[0], $server[1], $errstr, $errno, 5);`

Comment: More information is needed.  How are you connecting to these back-end servers?  If it's a simple HTTP API, there are a ton of off-the-shelf tools you can use for this... Nginx being one of them.  (In fact if you wanted, you could have several PHP-FPM application servers only and let Nginx balance them up front.)

Comment: Are the costs of each data request equal? I don't suspect so. So the best way to avoid overloading one server is to ask the servers which one is the least busiest at the time and let this one handle the request.

Comment: So you want to implement some kind of “poor man’s load balancing” in PHP, instead of using a _proper_ solution that was especially developed for this …?

Comment: The requests are pretty equally intense, at least from a bottleneck point of view. Brad suggested nginx. If nginx can be used for this, I'd love to. How can I send a request from php to nginx which will then rotate a predefined list of server ip+port?

Answer (score 1):

I'm reluctant to post an answer to this question because there's a multitude of possible answers, all of them valid to more or lesser degrees.

However, have you considered doing what you've hinted (keep a rotational increment to use) but instead of writing it to a database or disk file, store it in shared memory? This should be incredibly fast and accessible across processes. You can then hit each server in turn, per process.

If your PHP isn't compiled with any form of [shared memory](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php) and recompilation isn't possible, then look at writing a 'file' to `/dev/shm` (on Linux, anyway), which is a pseudo file system based in memory.

Caveats:

- A bottleneck may then be the memory segment itself. If your requests are relatively low and it's the processing that takes the time, (potentially true given your single front-end and multiple back-ends), this could be a possibility for you?
- It won't scale to more than 1 front-end server without using something like memcache.